# ON/OFF value status always offline

Tags: php, html, mysql, status

I have this code and when i click button "off"status is always off but in db is on

example

i click on at galery query in db set to value = 1 (on) but status says off

if i click off still say is off

show.php

```
    <?php
      $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pass", "strona");

        //----------
        function topnews()
        {
            $query="SELECT topnews FROM opcje";
            $topnews=$result=mysql_query($query);

            if($topnews == 1)
            {
                echo "<div id='on'>wlączone</div>";
            }
            else if($topnews == 0)
            {
                echo "<div id='off'>wyłączone</div>";
            }
        }
        //------------
        function galeria()
        {
            $query2="SELECT galeria FROM opcje";
            $galeria=$result=mysql_query($query2);

            if($galeria == 1)
            {
                echo "<div id='on'>wlączone</div>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div id='off'>wyłączone</div>";
            }
        }
        //--------------
        function logowanie()
        {
            $query3="SELECT logowanie FROM opcje";
            $logowanie=$result=mysql_query($query3);

            if($logowanie == 1)
            {
                echo "<div id='on'>wlączone</div>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div id='off'>wyłączone</div>";
            }
        }
        //--------------
        function rejestracja()
        {
            $query4="SELECT rejestracja FROM opcje";
            $rejestracja=$result=mysql_query($query4);

            if($rejestracja == 1)
            {
                echo "<div id='on'>wlączone</div>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div id='off'>wyłączone</div>";
            }
        }
      $mysqli->close();
    ?>
    <form action="onoff.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td><p><h3>Okienka na głównej</h3></p><hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Status<br></td>
        <td><?php topnews(); ?><br></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="wlacz" name="on"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="wylącz" name="off"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p><h3><hr>Galeria</h3></p><hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Status<br></td>
        <td><?php galeria(); ?><br></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="wlacz" name="on2"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="wylącz" name="off2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p><h3><hr>Logowanie</h3></p><hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Status<br></td>
        <td><?php logowanie(); ?><br></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="wlacz" name="on3"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="wylącz" name="off3"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p><h3><hr>Rejestracja</h3></p><hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Status<br></td>
        <td><?php rejestracja(); ?><br></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="wlacz" name="on4"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="wylącz" name="off4"/></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
```

onoff.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","strona");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Błąd podczas łączenia z bazą danych: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

    //===========//top news//===============//
        if(isset($_POST['on']))
        {
            $on = $_POST['on'];
            $sql = "UPDATE opcje SET topnews = '1'";
            echo "<script>alert('Włączono Pomyslnie');</script>";
            header("Refresh: 1; url=wlwyl.php");                    
        }   

        else if(isset($_POST['off']))
        {
            $off = $_POST['off'];
            $sql = "UPDATE opcje SET topnews = '0'";
            echo "<script>alert('Wyłączono Pomyslnie');</script>";
            header("Refresh: 1; url=wlwyl.php");    
        }  

    //===========//galeria//===============//
        if(isset($_POST['on2']))
        {
            $on2 = $_POST['on2'];
            $sql = "UPDATE opcje SET galeria = '1'";
            echo "<script>alert('Włączono Pomyslnie');</script>";
            header("Refresh: 1; url=wlwyl.php");                
        }   

        else if(isset($_POST['off2']))
        {
            $off2 = $_POST['off2'];
            $sql = "UPDATE opcje SET galeria = '0'";
            echo "<script>alert('Wyłączono Pomyslnie');</script>";
            header("Refresh: 1; url=wlwyl.php");    
        }  

    //===========//logowanie//===============//
        if(isset($_POST['on3']))
        {
            $on3 = $_POST['on'];
            $sql = "UPDATE opcje SET logowanie = '1'";
            echo "<script>alert('Włączono Pomyslnie');</script>";
            header("Refresh: 1; url=wlwyl.php");                    
        }   

        else if(isset($_POST['off3']))
        {
            $off3 = $_POST['off'];
            $sql = "UPDATE opcje SET logowanie = '0'";
            echo "<script>alert('Wyłączono Pomyslnie');</script>";
            header("Refresh: 1; url=wlwyl.php");    
        }  

    //===========//rejestracja//===============//
        if(isset($_POST['on4']))
        {
            $on4 = $_POST['on'];
            $sql = "UPDATE opcje SET rejestracja = '1'";
            echo "<script>alert('Włączono Pomyslnie');</script>";
            header("Refresh: 1; url=wlwyl.php");                
        }   

        else if(isset($_POST['off4']))
        {
            $off4 = $_POST['off'];
            $sql = "UPDATE opcje SET rejestracja = '0'";
            echo "<script>alert('Wyłączono Pomyslnie');</script>";
            header("Refresh: 1; url=wlwyl.php");    
        }

        //============//kiedys cos//==============//

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a ton of these in them:

```
if($topnews = 1)
```

This isn't what you want to do - It's assigning the value of `1` to `$topnews`, so this `if` statement is always true and is always executed. You're looking for:

```
if($topnews == 1)
```

Now, onto your code:

```
$topnews=$result=mysql_query($query);
```

[You shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). But, the value of `$topnews` is a MySQL result object, and doesn't have the value from the database. You need to fetch it, something similar to:

```
$result = mysql_query( $query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$topnews = $row['topnews'];
```

Comment: Works thanks
        $query="SELECT topnews FROM opcje";        $topnews=$result=mysql_query($query);        $result = mysql_query( $query);        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);        $topnews = $row['topnews'];